# How do I change the label text in one qml file from another qml file using Qt/QML/C++ in Cascades, Blackberry 10?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Say one file in assets folder is `RoomDetails.qml`:

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import "commons"

Page {
    Container {
         PageHeader{}

         //rest of the code
    }  
 }
```

And the other file in assets/commons folder is `PageHeader.qml`:

```
import bb.cascades 1.0


    Container {
         Label {
             id: dynamicLabel
         }

         //rest of the code
     }
```

Now, I want to change `dynamicLabel.text` from `RoomDetails.qml` to 'Room Details' and similarly from other qml files where `PageHeader` is included. What is the solution to this problem? It can be by using Qt or QML or C++. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I dont think you need to make Page as a root element of PageHeader.

Follwing is how PageHeader should look and you can define one property title as shown below, which you can access from QML which creates it.

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

Container {
    property alias title: dynamicLabel.text
    Label {
        id: dynamicLabel
    }
    //rest of the code
}
```

In RoomDetais QML, you can use PageHeader like below, and access label by accessing it's title property.

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import "commons"

Page {
    Container {
         PageHeader{
             title: "Room Details"
         }
         //rest of the code
    }  
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, my code for PageHeader is same as yours. Haven't slept in couple of days. Thank you for pointing out the typo.

Comment: I removed Page as root element from PageHeader, now root is Container

Comment: my sentence for PageHeader was little in-correct, i changed it